# What's the async for?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

Often we see pipe `|` and `async` in the value of an attribute/directive. For example

`<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows | async"`

May I ask what are they supposed for?

Comment: Was battling on how to use format function for ngx-datatable cells yesterday. Great answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

> Unwraps a value from an asynchronous primitive.

`async` pipe allows to avoid create variables or properties in TypeScipt. So we can use promises and observables in template.